Firestore security rules - securing collection group subpath based on resource.data
I have a Firestore collection group query like so:
collectionGroup('test').where('businessId', '==', '123').get()
I'm trying to secure it.
I have read I need to use wildcards to secure collection groups:
match /{path=**}/test/{testId}

How do I match resource.data.businessId to the wildcard path?
Basically if I have the following collections:
/businesses/123/test
/businesses/111/test

I need to extract the businessId from the path, so I can run the following function:
function canI(businessId) {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/businesses/$(businessId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.doIHaveAccess;
}

What do I write here:
match /{path=**}/test/{testId} {
   allow read: if canI(<get businessId somehow>)
}


Have a look at Structuring Cloud Firestore Security Rules and You can find more information about How security rules work.

Thanks, and I have, but it doesn't cover this specific case

Please edit your question and add a screenshot of your database. Please respond using @AlexMamo

@AlexMamo Why do you need a screenshot? Is there anything I can clarify for you?
